# What is git add -a?

Tags: git

I want only to add source file, not `exe` or object file in GitHub.
What should I do?

Can I use `git add -a` or others to add only all source file *without* adding `exe` or object file?

Comment: If you create an appropriate ignore file you can continue to use `-a`, but I'd still encourage you to review and think about what you're committing not just commit everything.

Comment: Use `.gitignore`

Answer (score 2):

Note: `git add -a` does not exists. `git add -A` does.

And you don't need to use explicitly this `-A` option, since it is the default when you specify the current path:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git add .
```

All you need is a [.gitignore file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), as one of [`gitignore.io`](https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore) or [`github/gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore).

You can test it with a `git status`: if you see a `file.exe`, that means the `.gitignore` is not present, or does not include an `*.exe` directive.

As soon as the `.gitignore` is there (even it is has not been added/committed itself), the git status will reflect its directives.